# Passing username and password securely between 2 backend systems endcrypted

Tags: java, security, encryption, key

What will be the most secure way in java to Pass username and password encrypted between 2 backend systems written in Java behind the vpn?

The goal will be that if the username and password encrypted being captured by someone, it could never be decrypted.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use TLS?

Comment: do you also want to somehow send the key of your encryption to the receiving end over the same medium or does the receiving end already has the key?

Answer (score 2):

Theoritically speaking, asymmetric encryption tools are used for transporting confidential data. Every node/client will has a pair of keys that one of them is private and only known by itself, and the other one is public and should be known by everbody that wants to send confidential data to that particular node. The thing is, if a payload data is encrypted with the **public** key of the client X, it can only be decrypted with the **private** key of the client X.

Protocols like SSL, TLS, etc. are some widely used implementations of that concept.

Comment: Thank you, so just passing this information over SSL (Https) should actually be "good enough" ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, it should be.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you can control both servers in an un-monitored manner(or at least not monitored by the intruder) and could implement any code on both servers then:
you can write your own made up protocol and its encryption algorithms on both systems and use it to share your data between your two systems.
this way the intruder would have no clue what the captured data even is or how to interpret them.

since you said 'Never be decrypted' your protocol could use an encryption key which is already defined on both servers and is not exchanged between them(over a handshake for example) and could use an encryption algorithm which doesn't store any encryption key validation in the transmitted data(like padding or hash etc) and of course shouldn't exchange the encryption algorithm.

it is worth noting that ssl/tls or any other protocol which expose their encryption algorithm and exchange encryption keys used are bad ideas to reach your goal since these protocols are prone to be deciphered if certain portions of their traffic are captured.

Answer (score -1):

The SHA (Secure Hash Algorithm) is one of the popular cryptographic hash functions. A cryptographic hash can be used to make a signature for a text or a data file.

The SHA-256 algorithm generates an almost-unique, fixed-size 256-bit (32-byte) hash. This is a one-way function, so the result cannot be decrypted back to the original value.

Currently, SHA-2 hashing is widely used as it is being considered as the most secure hashing algorithm in the cryptographic arena.

A few library like Guava or Apache commons codec provide the functions.

In your case, I suggest you send the Username in clear text, but send the password use the SHA encrypted, since it cannot be decrypted, in another backend system, you have save the enrypted String somewhere safe like Database, when the password send over, you just need to see the encrypted string match.

This is nice tutorial article talk about SHA in java:
https://www.baeldung.com/sha-256-hashing-java

Comment: SHA is irrelevant as a transport security tool.

Comment: Unfortunately, sending the password hashed with a one way function algorithm like SHA does not provide any security improvement. Yes, one can not encrypt the hashed string to get the actual password but practically the hash string becomes the password. for example, if i got the hash string as a hacker, i can simply send the exact request with the actual client.

Comment: sha family hash functions are brute-forcable specially if they are used to hash small strings like passwords also this would still expose the usernames, he want them not to be exposed.

Comment: good point, SHA should be used internally.  encrypt data with public key and decrypt it with private key (using RSA algorithm)  is a popular way.